# Insert HTTP não funciona Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, post, http-request

Fala galera, bom dia!
To a dois dias estudando sobre rotas de requisições HTTP, no meu GET eu consigo tranquilo, porém ao tentar usar o POST retorna o seguinte:

> **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

Alguem pode me ajudar? Ja tentei instalar o body-parse novamente, e nada.
Estou usando o isomnia para fazer as requisições

Segue o código está meio bagunçado mas segue...

```js
//CABEÇALHO
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 4200; //porta padrão
const sql = require('mssql');
const BASE = "";
const router = express.Router();
const Querys = require('./SQL/Querys')


//DEFININDO ROTA PRINCIPAL
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ STATUS: 'API FUNCIONANDO !' }));
app.use('/', router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//FAZENDO CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
sql.connect(BASE)
   .then(conn => global.conn = conn)
   .catch(err => console.log(err));



function SQLQuery(sqlQry, res) {
   global.conn.request()
      .query(sqlQry)
      .then(result => {
         res.json(result)
         // console.log(result.recordset)
      })
      .catch(err => res.json(err));
}

router.get('/processos', (req, res) => {
   SQLQuery(Querys.SProcess, res);
})

router.get('/processos/:name?', (req, res) => {
   let filter = '';
   if (req.params.name) 
   filter = "'" + (req.params.name) + "'";
   SQLQuery(Querys.SWProcess + filter, res);
})


  router.post('/processos', (req, res) =>{
      SQLQuery('INSERT INTO [dbo].[LOGB] VALUES('+ parseInt(req.body.id) +','+ req.body.nome +','+ req.body.setor +')', res);
  })


//inicia o servidor
app.listen(port);
console.log('API funcionando!');
```

Answer (score 2):

A partir do Express ^**4.16.0** o body-parser já está disponivel no framework com os métodos [urlencoded](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) e [json](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json), basta configurar no app.js

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Comment: Tentei fazer e ainda retornou o mesmo erro, em que parte do code eu declaro ?

Comment: Então o problema está no seu formulário..